# jQuery AJAX page refresh to show changes, followed by message feedback

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-ui, refresh

I have a Wordpress Lists Table, and each row has the option to be deleted.  When clicking `<a class="delete_gallery" href="&action=delete">` I have a jQueryUI Dialog pop up.  When confirming the action, ajax happens or whatever, and some server side stuff is processed.  On success, I want the page to refresh and a wordpress message to be displayed, explaining that the delete was successful.

The reason I want the page to refresh is because my WP_List_Table isn't ajaxified, and I need the change to be seen.

How do I display a message after the page is refreshed?  The way I currently have shows the message right after the refresh is called.  I don't want delays or anything: as soon as the confirmation in the dialog is clicked, I want the page to refresh, the server side stuff to happen, and then the success message to display.

Here is some of my code, with the server side var/info removed for simplicity.  Note:  I'm using Wordpress's built in Ajax.

```
jQuery(".delete_gallery").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();     
var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
var link = link.substring(0, link.indexOf('?'));

jQuery("#deleteconf").dialog({
  height: 150,
  width: 350,
  resizable : false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
      "Delete all items": function() {
     jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        jQuery.post(
        MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        {
        action : 'delete_gallery',
        postCommentNonce : MyAjax.postCommentNonce,
        },
    function(response) {
        window.location.reload(link);   
        jQuery('#message p').html('The gallery was deleted successfully');
        jQuery('#message').show();      
    }); return false;

    },
    Cancel: function() {
    jQuery(this).dialog("close"); return false;
    }
}
}); 

});
```

Is this the best way to do it? If so, how do I get the message to show up after the refresh.  If not, whats the best way? I would really like to use jQueryUI and I don't want someone to have to click like "okay, item was deleted" for the page to refresh and show the change.

I have something similar to this in place, but it uses a form and php to capture the button submit $_POST, and I'm not sure if that's possible when using jQueryUI Buttons.  Either way, it doesn't tackle the response after the refresh.

Thanks, and I appreciate all help.

Comment: why don't you just remove the row from the dom with js on ajaxsuccess ?

Comment: I should do that, but then I would have to count the rows and if it's the last row, display the "there is no data, please add some" message when everything else is deleted.  Regardless, I still want to know how to do what I described above, since I've wasted so much time on it!

Comment: @mikakun as I wait an answer, I implemented your solution.  This worked perfectly if removing one gallery from a page with many.  However, if there is more than one page of galleries, all rows get removed and it doesn't show the second page of galleries.  Thus, it looks like there are none when there really are!

Comment: get the next gallery back from the same ajax request that deletes the gallery

Comment: I'm not currently creating the tables via ajax, so I feel like it's much too much work to recreate them in jquery, especially when a page refresh would do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost 7 months later, and I've solved this, accidentally.

On the success of the AJAX response, instead of calling a refresh, I need to submit a form that has a hidden value, displaying the message I want to display.  If I wanted the message to be conditional, I could simply populate it prior to the form submission.

**html form**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="new-message-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="message" value="Success Message" />
</form>
```

**ajax response, on success**

```
function(response) {      
    $('#new-message-form').submit();    
});
```

**additional jquery** - this code grabs all $_POST and see's if the one you want exists.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // grab all $_POST
    var post = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;

    // if $_POST is set
    if('message' in post) {
        $('.success').html(post['message']); // display contents in .success
    }
});
</script>
```